# How can I get a bound control's client ID with javascript and/or server-side tags?

Tags: asp.net, tags, server-side, databound-controls, clientid

```
<asp:DataGrid>
    <ItemTemplate>
        1)
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbComments" onChange="javascript:checkLength(<%# tbComments.ClientId %>);" runat="server"/>
        2)
        <span id="<%# tbComments.ClientId %>Label"></span>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Any ideas to make the above working (which doesn't :P)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your markup to pass "this" as a reference to the given comments box.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbComments" 
           onChange="javascript:checkLength(this);" runat="server"/>
```

Then in your checkLength() function, "e" is a direct reference to the DOM element that raised the onchange event.

```
function checkLength(e){
  alert(e.id); //id of the comments box
  //get a reference to the span element immediately after the textbox
  theSpan = e.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];
  theSpan.innerHTML = "comments length: " + e.value.length;
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to use e.parentNode.getElementById instead,
I tried and it didn't work for me, is there any way?

Comment: Because the IDs are dynamically generated, the only way to get a reference to the span is by its position.

Comment: The client id of the label is the same as the client id of the textbox with a "Label" suffix, so if you know one, you know the other.

Comment: but how can I attach the suffix while I don't have the tbComments's clientId?

Comment: Why do you need the actual Id since you can get a reference the elements by traversing the DOM?

Comment: cuz i don't want it to be depended in the element's index in the DOM.
I have to many controls in this ItemTemplate and their amount varies dynmically as well.

Comment: You may have to look at a different approach instead of an itemtemplate. I would suggest you post a whole new question explaining your objectives and some more code. I think we will be able to provide you with alternatives.

Comment: ok, meanwhile im doin it this way, i simply included both in one div, so i don't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a class to the span or the textbox and use jQuery to find the element in the dom and add a change event to the textbox run the checkLength code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.myClass').change(function()
    {
         // do your length check...
    });
});
```

Comment: 1) I don't use jQuery in this project
2) where do I pass the ClientId?? it seems you didn't get my question
however don't bother yourself, It's been answered already.
Thanks for your effort.

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="tbComments" cssclass="myClass" runat="server"/>

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.myClass').change(function()
    {
         vat textbox = $(this);
         var span = textbox.next();
         span.html('comments length: ' + textbox.val().length);
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the problem isn't just the mispelling of "ClientId" in the following tag? :-)

```
<span id="<%# tbComments.CliendId %>Label"></span>
```

Comment: Sorry, you're right, but not that's the problem.
The problem is that it's generated dynamically since it's databound.

Answer (score 0):

Is there something wrong with your JavaScript checkLength() function not appending Label to the Client ID?  Then have your Javascript take both?:

```
<asp:DataGrid>
    <ItemTemplate>
        1)
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbComments"
            onChange="javascript:checkLength(<%# tbComments.ClientId %>, <%# tbComments.ClientId %>Label);"
            runat="server"/>
        2)
        <span id="<%# tbComments.ClientId %>Label"></span>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataGrid>
```